# How to let VSCode fix CakePHP warning : Undefined method 'redirect'

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, cakephp

I have a old project which use CakePHP 2.4.x ,and the project's path: /workspace/proA ,and use CakePHP framwork,but the CakePHP framework is in another path: /workspace/framework/CakePHP.
In VSCode IDE ,

```
<?php 
App::uses('BaseAppController',  'Controller');

$this->redirect('www.test.local');
```

[image]

and VSCode show me an warning:

```
   Undefined type 'App'
   Undefined method 'redirect'.
```

So how to fix it.I googled many days but no idea.

Comment: You need to add annotation (php doc) to your php file. But you are using old cakephp <=2, so I don't know how you will do it.

Comment: the project's CakePHP version is 2.4.x

Comment: Yeah, I wouldnt mind trying to solve an impossible task ;) Use a decent version of the framework and modern tooling will also be happy.